# Mount Freecom Classic SL Network Drive (NDAS) in Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: ubuntu, networking, hard-disk

Both the Network Drive and the Ubuntu machine are connected by Ethernet to a Linksys WRT54GL router (192.168.1.1).

To access the Network Drive in Windows, I installed the NDAS software and mounted the drive in read/write mode by entering a 20-digit device ID and corresponding 5-digit write key.

How do I mount the device in Ubuntu? Several questions on Ask Ubuntu mention Samba and CIFS. I'm guessing I will need to mount it as a network share, but I don't know how.

Is there a step-by-step guide for mounting NDAS devices in Ubuntu?